# remove a paritition table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, partitioning

I need to remove a partition table for an application upgrade. It is SQL Server 2008 R2.

The partition column is on column `col1` data type `smallint, null`. `Col1` has length `10` and precision `5`. As you can see the partition column is not the primary key.

I have three partitions. Left boundary <=boundary 2, 5 and the last one is empty. All of the partitions are on primary file group. There are no other filegroups.

Comment: Do you want to remove partition or Merge partition boundaries ?

Comment: Simplest would probably be: create a new table with the same structure but *not* against a partition scheme, insert/select, rename old table, rename new table, ultimately drop old table.

Answer (score -1):

@Kin yes he wants just to remove the partition so it becomes non- partitioned table.
 as Aaron said I would   select * into new_table from old_paritioned and rename the new table and drop the partitioned table.I am sure they are better ways of doing that though.
If it is large table(billion of rows) copying all rows takes time and resources.